# Handling large data from webservice to SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, web-services, sql-server-ce

In a windows mobile application I am calling a web service to retrieve large amounts of data which returns data in the form of array List. After that I am inserting the data to SQL Server CE database inside the device. Right now its taking too much time as there are lot of tables and large amount of data for each table. Please suggest a faster way to insert data to SQL Server CE database using Array list .

```
ce_command.Connection = Database.GetDbConnection();
ce_command.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
ce_command.CommandText = "NHH_SOURCE";
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeResultSet rsSource;
SqlCeUpdatableRecord recSource;
rsSource = ce_command.ExecuteResultSet(System.Data.SqlServerCe.ResultSetOptions.Updatable);
recSource = rsSource.CreateRecord();
NPFWebService.WebServiceGetNHH_Source[] get_source = null;
get_source = npf_WS.GetSourceData();

if (get_source.Length > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < get_source.Length; i++)
    {
        recSource.SetValue(0, get_source[i].sourceID);
        recSource.SetValue(1, get_source[i].sourceName.Replace("'", "''"));
        recSource.SetValue(2, get_source[i].organizationID);
        recSource.SetValue(3,get_source[i].transferF);
        recS‌​ource.SetValue(4, get_source[i].transferDate);
        rsSource.Insert(recSource);
```

Comment: Well, what does your code look like at the moment?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Thanks  for your response. following is a part of the code where im retrieving data from webservice using list and inserting data to sqlce database.

Comment: ce_command.Connection = Database.GetDbConnection();                        ce_command.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;                        ce_command.CommandText = "NHH_SOURCE";                     
  System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeResultSet rsSource;     SqlCeUpdatableRecord recSource;   rsSource = ce_command.ExecuteResultSet(System.Data.SqlServerCe.ResultSetOptions.Updatable);  recSource = rsSource.CreateRecord();              NPFWebService.WebServiceGetNHH_Source[] get_source = null;
get_source = npf_WS.GetSourceData();

Comment: if (get_source.Length > 0)
 { for (int i = 0; i < get_source.Length; i++) {                    recSource.SetValue(0, get_source[i].sourceID); recSource.SetValue(1, get_source[i].sourceName.Replace("'", "''"));recSource.SetValue(2, get_source[i].organizationID);recSource.SetValue(3,get_source[i].transferF);recSource.SetValue(4, get_source[i].transferDate);
rsSource.Insert(recSource);

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your are already using the fastest approach. Does you table have an index (or indexes) - you might be able to save some time by dropping and recreating after the insert is complete

Comment: thanx yes i created an index and its faster right now.Now i am facing another problem in retrieving data using webservice. GetSourceData() is returning nearly 100000 records and its take time to get the whole data on to the list while calling that method. Is there any easier way to retrieve the data ??